# Errno::EMFILE - "Too many open files @ rb_sysopen" when opening first file

Tags: ruby

I have an application that's using ruby 2.2.3 .  For most users the application is working fine but for 2 users they are running into the error "Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Roaming\Oneshot\save.dat (Errno::EMFILE)"

This is happening on the first file that the game tries to write to from the ruby level.  I've had the affected users run process explorer to check how many file handles the program has open but it only has 30 open at most, so I don't think they actually have too many open files.  The directory exists on the user's computer so it's not an issue with that either.  Does anyone have any ideas what else could be causing this error to be thrown?

This is the ruby code that's causing the issue, I don't think anything is wrong with it (it's breaking right when it opens, not during the dump):

```
def save
  if ($game_variables[3] == 0) #don't save if intro variable isn't set
    return
  end
  File.open(SAVE_FILE_NAME, 'wb') do |file|
    # Wrire frame count for measuring play time
    Marshal.dump(Graphics.frame_count, file)
    # Increase save count by 1
    $game_system.save_count += 1
    # Save magic number
    # (A random value will be written each time saving with editor)
    $game_system.magic_number = $data_system.magic_number
    # Write each type of game object
    Marshal.dump($game_system, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_switches, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_variables, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_self_switches, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_screen, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_actors, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_party, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_map, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_player, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_followers, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_oneshot, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_fasttravel, file)
    Marshal.dump($game_temp.footstep_sfx , file)
  end
  save_perma_flags
end
```

Comment: I'd be looking at 2 things: 1, is `.save` being called over and over again in a loop, or is `.save_perma_flags` calling into `.save` and getting into a recursive loop?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that `.save` isn't being looped, and neither is `.save_perma_flags` (it's not reaching this part at all).  Neither of the files created by `.save` or `.save_perma_flags` are actually being created (users checked the directory where the files are supposed to be post-crash), and when checking the open file handles with process explorer when the exception is hit it doesn't have either of these files open, so I'm pretty sure it's invoking the exception on the first pass.

Comment: Looking at the ruby source code, it tries to get files via `_open_osfhandle`, and if this fails it just assumes that the process has too many files open.  Is there any way to tell why `_open_osfhandle` would be failing for these users?  (I can recompile the ruby source)

Comment: Are you sure that directory exists?  I assume you're not hardcoding that c:\users... path and are using something like `ENV['APPDATA']` to get the appropriate base directory.

Comment: I'm sure the directory exists, the exception shows the directory when it fails and I've had the users affected navigate to the path to check that it did exist.

Comment: Another thing to note, this reportedly only happens for about 2 users out of our approximate 20k user base.  Save creation works fine for everyone else (including myself).